# UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput

Tags: ios6

I have been looking for a couple of days now and still cannot figure out how to get the password to verify itself, regardless of what I enter in the username and password field it will always move to the page even if the username/password is not what is defined.

EDIT - When my cancel button is clicked it will return to the page the login is located, but I need to have the password verified, just to clairfy

here is my code

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1){

        UITableViewController *alertView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ADTERM"];
        [self presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Login"])
    {
        UITextField *username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"Username:Test %@\nPassword:1234567891 %@", username.text, password.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have upvoted your post to give it more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use willDismissWithButtonIndex delegate method to verify which button has been pressed and from there do additional steps to see if they can either stay on the same view or if user has been validated load another view. use global variable like isVerified to determine the current state.

Comment: Okay I'm still a bit new to this but for the most part I have figured part of it out, all that remains that puzzles me is how would I go about implementing the isVerified variable and where would I place it?

Comment: place @property BOOL isVerified; in your header file so that it global within your class. Then in your implementation code if the user is verified set it to YES. This needs to done in alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton method

Comment: Here a really great tutorial that does what you need [http://raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1]

Comment: this is exactly what I need perfect, turns out I was only missing 2 lines of code.. thanks for all the great help!